# Submit button not emailing collected data from activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android

I am trying to collect data input from activity_main.xml using editText and email that data input from MainActivity.java when the submit button is clicked. For some reason the submit button does nothing when clicked. Any help is appreciated. Thank you. Below are my codes:

This is my activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/questions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.android.stool.MainActivity">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#303f9f"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:src="@drawable/logoconf" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/presentationName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:hint="@string/presentation"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:hint="@string/date"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/speaker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/speaker" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar1"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:isIndicator="false"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="0"
                android:stepSize="1"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar1_result"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                 />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/visuals"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/visuals" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar2"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:isIndicator="false"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="0"
                android:stepSize="1"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar2_result"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/useful"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/useful" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar3"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
                android:isIndicator="false"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="0"
                android:stepSize="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar3_result"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recommend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:text="@string/recommend" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/yes_radio_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/y"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/no_radio_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/n"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/suggestions"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:hint="@string/suggestions"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/review_summary_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Summary"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/questions"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
            android:onClick="submit"
            android:text="@string/submit" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.android.stool;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText presentationName;
    EditText date;
    RatingBar rating_bar1;
    RatingBar rating_bar2;
    RatingBar rating_bar3;
    RadioButton yes;
    RadioButton no;
    EditText suggestions;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText editText;
    private EditText dateText;
    private TextView textView;
    private RatingBar ratingBar1;
    private TextView rating_bar1_result;
    private TextView rating_bar2_result;
    private TextView rating_bar3_result;
    private TextView visualsText;
    private RatingBar ratBar;
    private TextView usefulText;
    private RatingBar ratiBar;
    private TextView recommendText;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton yesButton;
    private RadioButton noButton;
    private EditText suggestText;
    private Button submitButton;
    private String str;
    int count;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
        coolLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.presentationName);
        recDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        comCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
        rating_bar1 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar1);
        rating_bar1_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar1_result);
        graPhics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.visuals);
        rating_bar2 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar2);
        rating_bar2_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar2_result);
        advAnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.useful);
        rating_bar3 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar3);
        rating_bar3_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar3_result);
        menDar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recommend);
        yesButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yes_radio_button);
        noButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.no_radio_button);
        sugGest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suggestions);

    }


    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        public void onClick (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: example@gmail.com")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Presentation Review for: " + name);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        displayMessage(priceMessage);

    });

    }


    private String reviewOrderSummary(String cool, String name, String rec, String com, boolean rating_bar1_result, String gra, boolean rating_bar2_result, String adv, boolean rating_bar3_result, String men, boolean selectedId, String sug) {
        String priceMessage = "Logo: " + cool;
        priceMessage += "\nName of Presentation: " + name;
        priceMessage += "\nDate: " + rec;
        priceMessage += "\nQuestion: " + com;
        priceMessage += "\nPerformance: " + rating_bar1_result;
        priceMessage += "\nQuestion: " + gra;
        priceMessage += "\nVisual: " + rating_bar2_result;
        priceMessage += "\nQuestion: " + adv;
        priceMessage += "\nUseful Information: " + rating_bar3_result;
        priceMessage += "\nQuestion: " + men;
        priceMessage += "\nAnswer: " + selectedId;
        priceMessage += "\nSuggestion: " + sug;
        priceMessage += "\nThank you!";
        return priceMessage;
    }


    //displays Logo
    private void displayImage(View ImageView) {
    ImageView coolLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    coolLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoconf);
    String cool = coolLogo.getRootView().toString();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)

    {
        // ImageView.getDisplay();
        coolLogo.getDisplay();
    }
    }

    //displays Presentation Name
    private void displayText(String name) {
    EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.presentationName);
        name = nameField.getText().toString();
        if(name.equals(""))

    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please type the Name of the Presentation!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else

    {
        // EditText.setText(name);
        nameField.setText(name);
    }
    }


    //displays Date
    private void displayDate(String rec) {
    EditText recDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        rec = recDay.getText().toString();
        if(rec.equals(""))

    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please type in Today's Date!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else

    {

        // EditText.setText(name);
        recDay.setText(rec);
    }
    }



    //displays How would you rate the speaker's TextView
    private void displaySpeaker(String com) {
    TextView comCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
        com = comCat.setText().toString();
        // TextView.setText(com);
        comCat.setText(com);
    }


    //displays the Rating Bar1 below speaker's TextView

    void RatingUpdate() {
        rating_bar1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                rating_bar1_result.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(Math.round(rating)));

            }
        });
    }


    //displays how helpful were the visuals TextView
    private void displayVisuals(String gra) {
    TextView graPhics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.visuals);
        gra = graPhics.getText().toString();
        // TextView.setText(gra);
        graPhics.setText(gra);
    }


    //displays the Rating Bar below visuals TextView
    void RatingUpdate2() {
        rating_bar2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                rating_bar2_result.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(Math.round(rating)));

            }
        });
    }


    //displays useful TextView
    private void displayVisuals(String adv) {
    TextView advAnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.useful);
        adv = advAnt.getText().toString();
        // TextView.setText(adv);
        advAnt.setText(adv);
    }


    //displays the Rating Bar below useful TextView
    void RatingUpdate3() {
        rating_bar3.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                rating_bar3_result.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(Math.round(rating)));

            }
        });
    }


    //displays recommend TextView
    private void displayRecommend(String men) {
    TextView menDar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recommend);
        men = menDar.getText().toString();
        // TextView.setText(men);
        menDar.setText(men);

    //checks radiobutton for recommend TextView
    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedId ==-1)

    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please choose one!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else

    {
        yesButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        if (yesButton.getId() == R.id.yes_radio_button) {
        }

        noButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        if (noButton.getId() == R.id.no_radio_button) {
        }
    }
    }


    //displays  additional suggestions
    private void displaySuggestions(String sug) {
    EditText sugGest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suggestions);
        sug = sugGest.getText().toString();
        if(sug.equals(""))

    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please type in your suggestions!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else

    {

        // EditText.setText(name);
        sugGest.setText(sug);
    }



        Toast.makeText(

    getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for filling this survey!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).

    show();

    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given review text on the screen.
     */
    private void displayMessage(String message) {
        TextView reviewSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.review_summary_text_view);
        reviewSummaryTextView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

**My error codes are below:**

For the codes below, all names before the = sign is red. So, coolLogo is red, nameField is red, recDay is red, comCat is red, graPhics is red, advAnt is red,  menDar is red, and sugGest is red.

```
coolLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.presentationName);
    recDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    comCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
    graPhics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.visuals);
    advAnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.useful);
    menDar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recommend);
    sugGest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suggestions);
```

For the code below,setOnClickListener is red, v is red, name is red, priceMessage is red, and ) before the ; is red.

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        public void onClick (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: example@gmail.com")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Presentation Review for: " + name);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        displayMessage(priceMessage);

    });

    }
```

I would like to be able to collect the logo, date, questions, and answers, and email them to example@gmail.com.

Comment: remove  android:onClick="submit" from xml in button widget

Comment: Actually, I really want you compile this code, and I suggest you remove this question after finished. This question is useful only for you, not for community.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1:**

With this way, at least, you can display your message.

1. You have two `displayVisuals(String gra)` method. Remove one of them.

=>

```
//displays how helpful were the visuals TextView
private void displayVisuals(String gra) {
    TextView graPhics = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.visuals);
    gra = graPhics.getText().toString();
    // TextView.setText(gra);
    graPhics.setText(gra);
}
```

2. Change setText() to getText() in `displaySpeaker()` method.

=>

```
private void displaySpeaker(String com) {
    TextView comCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
    com = comCat.getText().toString();
    // TextView.setText(com);
    comCat.setText(com);
}
```

3. And, Remove your `onCreate()` method and `submitButton.setOnClickListener ~`. Add this:

=>

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.presentationName);
            EditText recDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
            TextView comCat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speaker);
            TextView menDar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recommend);
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
            EditText sugGest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suggestions);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: example@gmail.com")); // only email apps should handle this
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Presentation Review for: " + nameField.getText().toString());
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            String priceMessage = reviewOrderSummary(
                    "Logo", /* Logo is an image, and you printing string. Is that what you meant? */
                    nameField.getText().toString(),
                    recDay.getText().toString(),
                    comCat.getText().toString(),
                    true, /* rating_bar1_result is a TextView, and you printing boolean. Is that what you meant? */
                    "GRA", /* Indefinite */
                    true, /* rating_bar2_result is a TextView, and you printing boolean. Is that what you meant? */
                    "ADV", /* Indefinite */
                    true, /* rating_bar3_result is a TextView, and you printing boolean. Is that what you meant? */
                    menDar.getText().toString(),
                    radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == 0,
                    sugGest.getText().toString()
            );
            displayMessage(priceMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Can you build this code? I think it cannot be compiled.
You must set your value to instance, not a class itself!

```
// ImageView.getDisplay();
coolLogo.getDisplay();


// EditText.setText(name);
nameField.setText(name);


// TextView.setText(adv);
advAnt.setText(adv);
```

Comment: I changed the ImageView, EditText, and TextView to the format above...I'm have a few errors in my code and I don't know why...

Comment: @Gifer So, update your question. Show me your error code.

Comment: Thanks @Stanley Kou, I have updated it to include the current errors.

Comment: Thanks @Stanley Kou, the only thing highlighted in red now is reviewOrderSummary, it says cannot resolve method 'reviewOrderSummary'.

Comment: @Gifer You have `reviewOrderSummary` method in your MainActivity.java!

Comment: yes I do but for some reason Android studio has highlighted it in red.